# Why does the Firebase Email Verification take a long time to deliver after user creation on Web?

Tags: angular, email, firebase, firebase-authentication

**Environment:**

- Web/Angular4
- (package) firebase v4.3

**Case:**

- User lands on our website and decides to sign up.
- User chooses Email/password as authentication type.
- User enters Email and Password.
- Login Is created in Firebase and Verification Email is sent.
- User is asked to verify email before proceeding and is logged out
  of the site.

My issue is that the verification email is taking around 30 minutes to deliver, which is an issue as we would like them to be able to verify almost immediately so the user can proceed with their enrollment/order.

Is the delay because the firebase email servers are backed up?

Is there a way the delivery can be sped up?

Thanks,
Matt Tipping

Comment: I opened a new issue on github based on this question: [Issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web/issues/234)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I might aswell write answer on this so it doesn't stay open.

**bojeil-google** answered following to Github issue based on this question:

> Hey @eljass this is due to some issue with SendGrid service which
>   Firebase Auth uses to send emails (password reset, email verification,
>   etc). In case you are still experiencing these delays, please file an
>   issue there: https://firebase.google.com/support/

Here is the link for the issue: [Github issue #234](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web/issues/234)